# Registering an xll addin outside a loop

Tags: loops, xlwings

This code takes 6 minutes to do a few calculations looping over 2K xlsx files containing 39 X 10 cells of stock fundamentals data.  I would like to know if it could be speeded up by registering the xll addin before the beginning of the loop. If I manually run stock after stock I don't have to keep reinstalling the addin.

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
# ?Workaround possible to place registration here
stocks = next(os.walk(path5))[2]
for stock in stocks:
    wb = xw.Book(path5 + stock)
    wb.app.api.RegisterXLL('C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/AddIns/vsoft15.xll')
    ws = wb.sheets[0]
    // do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing, you also don't have to instantiate a book object with every loop:

```py
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book(path5 + stock)
wb.app.api.RegisterXLL('C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/AddIns/vsoft15.xll')
ws = wb.sheets[0]
stocks = next(os.walk(path5))[2]
for stock in stocks:
    # do stuff: ws['A1'].value
```